# js-ctypes from javascript objects

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I'm working on a Firefox extension that receives binary images as **ArrayBuffers** of **uint8_t**.

In my extension I load a .dll file that has a function that I need to use on that received image. The function takes a **ctype.uint8_t.ptr** parameter and returns a **ctype.uint8_t.ptr** value.

I can't seem to find a way of converting the **ArrayBuffer** to this particular ctype so that I can pass it along to the function. Is there a correct way to do this?

Using ImplicitConvert() gives an *Error: argument must be a nonnegative integer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do just:

```
var a = new Uint8Array(1<<10);
var ptr = new ctypes.uint8_t.ptr(a.buffer);
```

The stuff is not documented it seems, but there are [some tests](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/ctypes/tests/unit/test_jsctypes.js.in#1756) that demonstrate this.

Comment: Might be working but I get the following error : TypeError: expected type pointer, got (void 0)

Comment: I assume that somehow I end up having invalid data in a.buffer. Is there a way to treat for this? According to the length attribute of the new Uint8Array I create, the length is 19.

Comment: It works. Thank you for your answer. But I'm still curious about how to check the array prior to trying to point to it. I can use try and catch blocks but knowing beforehand might be more effective.

Comment: I don't know anything about your code and therefore cannot reproduce your problem, so I won't speculate here. ;)

Comment: Hey @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc and nmair the link to the "some tests" is broken, i was wondering if this method still works today and where these test cases are. This is really really cool!

Comment: @Noitidart Hi there! Here's a working link to the tests : https://github.com/krad-radio/mozilla-krad/blob/master/toolkit/components/ctypes/tests/unit/test_jsctypes.js.in

Comment: Thanks so much @Sebastian-LaurenţiuPlesciuc ! :)