# "memset" has no DLL so how ctype it

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, jsctypes

How to use `memset` in jsctypes. There no DLL for it. I searched/scoured js ctype codes but couldn't find an example to rip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to `memset` an array to zero-bytes, then I have "Good news, everyone": js-ctypes will initialize new arrays to zero.

Otherwise it would be probably easiest to just create a typed array, initialize it, and [create a pointer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386469/484441).

Apparently you can also set array elements directly on a ctypes array these days (provided the array type has a known size)...

```
// Note that size is the number of array elements to set,
// not the number of bytes.
function memset(array, val, size) {
 for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
   array[i] = val;
 }
}

var a = ctypes.uint8_t.array()(10);
memset(a, 0xde, a.length);
console.log(a.toSource());
// "ctypes.uint8_t.array(10)([222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222, 222])"
```

Comment: Are you kidding me, thats it? Dude I got some fundamental issues, i searched the world..... How can I learn to be a js-ctype expert? :(

Comment: First become a C and C++ expert, and then Javascript expert. The dive into (js-)ctypes by trial and error. The rest afterwards is easy :p. Nah, I wouldn't call myself an expert to be honest, but "knowledgeable" maybe.

Comment: :( i'll try to start with learning about those ctypes arrays they are totally different than what I'm used to i think.

Comment: i think im reaching js-ctypes expert status :D i just deployed my first addon heavily relying on jsctypes, it needs perf improvment but man these comments made me reminisce! Check it out! https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nativeshot/