# memset for structure vs array in js-ctypes

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, jsctypes

This is regarding the question [memset has no DLL so how ctype it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466228/memset-has-no-dll-so-how-ctype-it) in combination with [Any ideas what fillchar is doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481621/any-ideas-what-fillchar-is-doing/24485847)

I learned that `memset` can be used with `array` and `structure` type. However there is no `sizeof` feature so we have to do `.length` for arry and `.size()` for structure no?

I'm just a bit confused at how memset can work on structure and array please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the ctypes `memset` I provided can be used with arrays. But structures can be cast to arrays.

*Normally* you'd not use `memset` on a structure, except when you want want to initialize it to 0s. But then again, normally you don't need to initialize it to 0 if you create the structure instance yourself with ctypes, as ctypes will take care of that (so you'd only need to initialize it when it is allocated by external code for whatever reason).

*Normally* you'd just set the members of the structure:

```
var tbb = new struct_TBButton();

tbb.iBitmap = 1;
tbb.idCommand = 2;
```

In the really *unusal* case you need to `memset` it, then cast it to a (byte) array, which you can then `memset`.

```
// Cast to a byte array (uint8_t == byte)
var a = ctypes.cast(b, ctypes.uint8_t.array(struct_TBButton.size));

// memset to something.
// memset function from other question.
function memset(array, val, size) {
 for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
   array[i] = val;
 }
} 
memset(a, 0x10, a.length);

// verify by checking iBitmap, which is an int(32), so 4 bytes,
// so should be 10101010.
console.log(tbb.iBitmap, tbb.iBitmap.toString(16), b.iBitmap == 0x10101010);
//  269488144 "10101010" true
```

Comment: Thanks very much, memset was a fundemental thing I wasn't understanding, this helps me a ton.